# Angular component that encapsulates <li> tag

Tags: css, angular

Suppose I have some styled list:

```
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Now I want to encapsulate each `<li>` item into separate component. Doing that, we get something like this in a resulting DOM:

```
<ul>
  <my-item><li>...</li></my-item>
  <my-item><li>...</li></my-item>
  ...
</ul>
```

The problem is, it breaks styling. We will get wrong margins between items, wrong borders etc. And if we use external CSS, the problem becomes nasty.

So, is there a way to apply `<li>` styles directly to `<my-item>` without editing external CSS file? In AngularJS there is a `replace` option for directives, but in Angular it doesn't exist afaik.

Comment: What library are you using?, usually you have the same element selector within a class.

Comment: Why do you need <my-item> to wrap an <li> ? Can't you simply use a directive (<li my-item></li> or just <my-item>) ? or even simplier, ngRepeat ?

Comment: enguerranws, in Angular 2 directives aren't supposed to have a template. What if I need to display some data inside? Sure, it's doable with an extra DOM manipulations, but I don't think it's a good idea. On the other hand, components alway wrap their content into an outer tag.

Comment: @troorl which library are you using?, again, it should have the styles matching a css class instead of just the html element.

Comment: @troorl What do you mean by "in Angular2 directives aren't supposed to have a template." If you want to add content, use a component instead of a directive. Components have a template.

Comment: @LeandroZubrezki im using bootstrap 3.3.7 and i have the same situation and a more complex as i need to show submenus i would be calling the encapsualted component recursively please help as i m clueless about this..

Answer (score 16):

**Angular2 answer**

As @enguerranws mentioned use an attribute selector for your component instead of a tag selector

```
@Component(selector: '[myLi]', ...
//@Component(selector: '[my-li]', ...
```

and use it like

```
<li myLi>...
<!-- <li my-li>... -->
```

Angular2 doesn't have the `replace` option and it's also deprecated in Angular 1.x since a while.

To allow users of your `<my-li>` to pass custom content add a `<ng-content></ng-content>` tag to the template (you can add custom content before and after the `<ng-content>` tag that should appear for each `<my-li>` element.

```
@Component(
  selector: '[myLi]', // '[my-li]', 
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
  ...)
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you can't add attributes on the li tag inside the component, for example ng-class. Or is it possible ?

Comment: Sure. You can add `@HostBinding('attr.someattr') isSomeAttr:boolean = false;`. If you set `this.isSomeAttr = true;`, then the attribute `someattr` will be added like  `<li my-li someattr>`

Comment: Oops my bad, I am trying to do this with Angular 1.5 component and I thought this question was about them.

Comment: That's because it's not clear from the question :-/ I made it more prominent in the answer.

Comment: Can you fix your syntax? It should be selector: '[custom-attribute-name]', rather than an array with the string in it.

Answer (score -1):

Kinda Late but what about using the following solution

```
<ul>
  <my-item class='myLi'>...</my-item> <!-- or -->
  <my-item [ngClass.myLi]='isList'>...</my-item> 
  ...
</ul>
```

and on your css:

```
.myLi {
    display: list-item;
    // and everything else you've styled your li
}
```