# How to eliminate inner component when using ng-content

Tags: angular, angular2-ngcontent

I'm trying to factor out popup menus so I can write this:

```
<panel-menu>
  <panel-menu-item>Edit input</panel-menu-item>
  <panel-menu-item>Edit mappings</panel-menu-item>
  <panel-menu-item divider-before>Show agent code</panel-menu-item>
</panel-menu>
```

I have a `panel-menu` component with this HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group" [class.open]="...">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="..."><i class="ion-gear-b icon-lg"></i></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
    <ng-content select="panel-menu-item"></ng-content>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and `panel-menu-item` with this HTML:

```
<li *ngIf="dividerBefore" class="divider"></li>
<li><a><ng-content></ng-content></a></li>
```

The problem is that the resulting DOM has a `panel-menu-item` between the `ul` and the `li`, which breaks the third-party CSS.

Is there some way to project just the *content* of the selected children, and not the children themselves?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35221283/56050) suggests to use an attribute on the `li` instead of a component, but that leaks implementation. Users of `panel-menu` shouldn't need to know what elements menu items are implemented as.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To project just content you should wrap your content in embedded view like:

**panel-menu-item.component.ts**

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'panel-menu-item',
  template: `
    <ng-template>
      <li *ngIf="dividerBefore" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a><ng-content></ng-content></a></li>
    </ng-template>
  `
})
export class PanelMenuItemComponent {
  @ViewChild(TemplateRef) content: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

In the preceding code i'm wrapping template in `ng-template` tag and getting `TemplateRef` instance from it by using `@ViewChild` decorator.

Having `TemplateRef` we can easily manage where to insert the template:

**panel-menu.component.ts**

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'panel-menu',
  template: `
    <div class="btn-group" >
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Some button</button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of menuItems">
          <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="item.content"></ng-container>
        </ng-container>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `
})
export class PanelMenuComponent {
  @ContentChildren(PanelMenuItemComponent) menuItems: QueryList<PanelMenuItemComponent>;

  constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

I'm using `@ContentChildren` to get hold of our panel-menu items and then just use built-in directive [NgTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet) to place content inside `ul`.

We have to run the second digest cycle by using `this.cdRef.detectChanges();` because we'll get error

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value:
>   '[object Object]'.

as soon as  `@ViewChild(TemplateRef) content` updates its value during change detection.

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ywbb8e?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using `ContentChildren`, but with `ElementRef`. The template part here is the missing piece that should clean it up.

Comment: The big downside I see with this approach is you'll probably want to do `<panel-menu-item (click)="click()">Something</panel-menu-item>` and any outputs on the menu item won't work.

Comment: Even though the click event on the menu item is lost, you can work around this by setting up an output called 'click' on the menu item component, then calling that output when you click on the inner `<a>` element.